# FetchResultController delegate - incompatible types warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to connect my CoreData to iCloud using NSFetchedResultController basing on [iCloud example](http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452).

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:@"Root1"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

However i get such warning on second line:
warning: Semantic Issue: Passing 'RootViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'. I think that setting delegate to self should be ok, but it's not. Anybody can help?

Comment: Make `RootViewController` conform to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Does your class implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `RootViewController` conform to the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```